# AngularJs + Laravel Routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, laravel

I want to remove # hash in angularJs using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); but this is causing all URLs to be routed through angularJs. How can I set it up so only some pre-defined URLs got routed through angularJs, while the rest still using Laravel.

The code is:

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/alls', {
                templateUrl: app.site_url + 'ang/index',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .when('/alls/page/:page', {
                templateUrl: app.site_url + 'ang/index',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/alls'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    ]);
```

So if it's not /alls or /alls/page/, Laravel should handle the routing.

Comment: Are you using any server side rewriting?

Comment: @Christian: Yes, other urls should go through index.php. I use htaccess to re-write:  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: and from where do you serve the frontend? From the /public directory?

Comment: Yes, public directory. If I set html5Mode as false, they work fine, using: 
`http://www.domain.com/alls/#/
http://www.domain.com/alls/#/page/10`
With this setting, I can go to http://www.domain.com/about, and the page will refresh and display the content correctly. But I want to remove the # hash by setting html5Mode as true, like so:
`http://www.domain.com/alls/
http://www.domain.com/alls/page/10`
But now, when I go to http://www.domain.com/about, the page won't refresh, and it's not displaying the content of about page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried using `<base href=".">` as explained in: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location. But it doesn't work.
I finally got it to work. Here is the solution:

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/alls', {
            templateUrl: app.site_url + 'ang/index',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/alls/page/:page', {
            templateUrl: app.site_url + 'ang/index',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: app.site_url + 'ang/index',
             controller: function(){
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }               
        });           
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

Hopefully it will help someone else.